# How to change numpy array by removing quotations and adding a comma between each value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

If I have an array like this:

```
 array([['10      2       1967    19.7    7.5'],
        ['10      3       1967    18.3    21.0'],
        ['10      4       1967    17.6    0.0']])
```

How do I remove the quotations and add a comma in between each value? Such that I get something like this:

```
 array([[10, 2, 1967, 19.7, 7.5],
        [10, 3, 1967, 18.3, 21.0],
        [10, 4, 1967, 17.6, 0.0]])
```

Comment: Do you want to convert the single numbers to something? `int` or `float`? With a numpy array you can't mix both.

Comment: What the source of this array?  It would be better to correct it before it's created, rather fix it after.  The source and targets are very different arrays.  One is 1d with string elements.  The other is 2d with numeric elements.  The quotes and commas tell us about the arrays, but they aren't what define them.

Comment: I missed something before.  Your source array is 2d, with shape (3,1).  I neglected that inner set of [].  The key descriptors of a numpy array are shape and dtype.

Answer (score 2):

Regular NumPy arrays must have a single `dtype`. In this case, `float` may be appropriate:

```
A = np.array([['10      2       1967    19.7    7.5'],
              ['10      3       1967    18.3    21.0'],
              ['10      4       1967    17.6    0.0']])

B = np.array([x[0].split() for x in A], dtype=float)

# array([[   10. ,     2. ,  1967. ,    19.7,     7.5],
#        [   10. ,     3. ,  1967. ,    18.3,    21. ],
#        [   10. ,     4. ,  1967. ,    17.6,     0. ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

```
from numpy import array
import ast
l = array([['10      2       1967    19.7    7.5'],
        ['10      3       1967    18.3    21.0'],
        ['10      4       1967    17.6    0.0']])

l = [list(map(ast.literal_eval,  j.split()))  for i in l for j in i]
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 2, 1967, 19.7, 7.5], [10, 3, 1967, 18.3, 21.0], [10, 4, 1967, 17.6, 0.0]]
```

Note: You cannot have both int and float in np.array.

Answer (score 0):

Other couple of options:

```
array = np.array([['10      2       1967    19.7    7.5'],
                  ['10      3       1967    18.3    21.0'],
                  ['10      4       1967    17.6    0.0']])

new_ary1 = np.array([ [ float(n) for n in e[0].split() ] for e in array ])
new_ary2 = np.array([ np.array(e[0].split(), dtype=float) for e in array ])
```